# Picker drops selected segment when data changed

Tags: swiftui, observable, picker

I got a problem with Picker. When I try to change state of data in selected segment it's drops it (gif attached). How I can have stay selected segment in Picker when displaying data is changed (when I press "love" button, selected segment should stay without changes)

Single item has option:

```
struct Landmark: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
var id: Int
var name: String
var imageName: String
var mainImage: Image {
    Image(imageName)
var liked: Bool
var popular: Bool
var recommended: Bool
}
```

I got class with array of objects:

```
final class ModelData: ObservableObject {
@Published var landmarks: [Landmark]
}
```

And trying use picker like that:

```
struct tempSegmentControl: View {

@EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData

@State private var selected = ModelData().landmarks

var popularLandmarks: [Landmark] {
    modelData.landmarks.filter { landmark in
        (landmark.popular)
    }
}

var rocommendedLandmarks: [Landmark] {
    modelData.landmarks.filter { landmark in
        (landmark.recommended)
    }
}

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Selection", selection: $selected) {
                Text("All").tag(modelData.landmarks)
                Text("Popular").tag(popularLandmarks)
                Text("Recommended").tag(rocommendedLandmarks)

            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.95)
            
            ForEach(selected, id: \.id) { land in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: DetailView2(landmark: land)) {
                    MainItem3(landmark: land)
                    }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

[Drop selected segment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3uwn.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selection:` isn't going to work properly with an array type like this (`[Landmark]`).

Instead, you'll probably want to do something simple like:

```
@State private var selection = 0
//...
Picker("Selection", selection: $selection) {
   Text("All").tag(0)
   Text("Popular").tag(1)
   Text("Recommended").tag(2)
```

And then use a computed property for your array that you iterate through later:

```
var selected : [Landmark] {
  switch selection {
    case 0:
      return modelData.landmarks
    case 1:
      //etc
  }
}
```

You could do this with an `enum : Int` as well, which would probably be a little safer later on if you cases expand (and it would give you a limited set in your computed property).